# Losing a bouncing ball's position

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I'm trying to draw a Bouncing ball using WIN32 GUI, so i define a 2d vector for ball position
and a rectangle map with my screen size

```
struct pos {
    float x;
    float y;
};
RECT maprect = {0, 0, 800, 600};
pos ballpos;
ballpos.x=300;
ballpos.y=300;
```

(of course im using a class for 2dvec and it's more than this)

and i draw a ellipse

```
Ellipse(backbufferDC, (int)ballpos.x-45, (int)ballpos.y-45,
        (int)ballpos.x+45, (int)ballpos.y+45);
```

now to make my ellipse bounce i use this code in in my message loop and it works fine:

```
bool balldown = false; 
if (ballpos.y > maprect.bottom-40) {
    balldown = true;
}
else if (ballpos.y < maprect.top+300) {
    balldown = false;
}

if (ballpos.y > maprect.bottom-40) {
    balldown = true ;
}
else if(ballpos.y < maprect.top+300) {
    balldown = false;
}

if (!balldown) {
    vel+=1;
    ballpos.y +=3;
}
else {
    ballpos.y-=3;
}


Ellipse(bbdc, (int)tankpos.x-45, (int)tankpos.y-45,
        (int)tankpos.x+45, (int)tankpos.y+45);
```

but to make it look more realistic i decided to change the ball velocity on the move 
so i end up with this code

```
float vel;
if (ballpos.y > maprect.bottom-40) {
    balldown = true ;
}
else if (ballpos.y < maprect.top+300) {
    balldown = false ;
}

if (!balldown) {
    vel+=0.5f;
    ballpos.y +=vel;
}
else {
    vel-=0.5f;
    ballpos.y-=vel;
}



Ellipse(bbdc, (int)tankpos.x-45, (int)tankpos.y-45,
        (int)tankpos.x+45, (int)tankpos.y+45);
```

and it looks much better now, but the problem is the ball just bounces once, then the second time it goes into the ground and disappears!

Comment: Did you check against value truncations? Did you make sure that there are no negative values being passed around that might cause incorrect screen coords?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!balldown) {
    vel+=0.5f;
    ballpos.y +=vel;
}
else {
    vel-=0.5f;
    ballpos.y-=vel;
}
```

This logic is wrong.  Gravity always causes acceleration in the same direction, down.

What you should do is handle collision.  An elastic collision with a massive wall could look like

```
vel = -vel;
```

So in the end you have

```
vel -= 0.5f;
ballpos.y += vel;
if (ballpos.y <= floory) {
    vel = -vel;
    ballpos.y = 2*floory - ballpos.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 else {
        vel-=0.5f;
        ballpos.y-=vel;
      }
```

You might be getting the negative values here.

Comment: i tried ..... int vel=1; if(!balldown){
    vel+=1;
    ballpos.y +=vel;
}else {
vel-=1;
ballpos.y-=vel;
} but i get the same result

Comment: @Max, the best way to solve this is either save the outputs to the file or just print them to the screen with out the bouncing ball being drawn. Should help you in pin pointing the error.

Comment: probably somewhere i get a negative value i should check the vel

Comment: @Max, well hope you nail the problem :)